# Helvetica for latin characters in a mixed document with latin and cyrillic

Tags: bibliographies, biber, cyrillic, russian, helvetica

I have a document with English and Russian in both the main document and in the citations. For the latin characters I want to set Helvetica. But since Helvetica and/or the T1 encoding is not available in cyrillic the compilation of the cyrillic text fails. In the example below I tried adding additional encodings to overcome the problem, but with no success. The font of the cyrillic text is less important - it can be any sans serif font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{lit.bib}
@book{book1,
    annote = {http://www.apmath.spbu.ru/ru/staff/pronina/publications.html},
    author = {Ю. Г. Пронина},
    date-added = {2021-10-15 22:35:00 +0200},
    date-modified = {2021-10-15 22:35:00 +0200},
    publisher = {СПбГУ},
    title ={Сборник задач по основам теории упругости: учебное пособие},
    year = {2003},
    langid = {russian}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=bibtex]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{lit.bib}

\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german,russian,main=english]{babel}

\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}

\begin{document}
Ggeabt Клэ \footcite{book1}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to switch the language explicitly. Then add `\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T2A}{phv}{cmss}` (admittedly, not the best match).

Comment: That may work, but I don't know how to specify that cyrillic should be in T2A and the rest in T1?

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying, by using `unicode-math` package, and also:

Since `Babel` package can use Lualatex's ability to auto-detect scripts, and, with Lualatex's ability to use TrueType/OpenType system fonts, there is no longer any need to employ 8-bit fonts from last century with their encodings.

Plus, `biber` as the backend for `biblatex`.

Blue is Cyrillic, to highlight it:

[image: modern toolchain]

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{book1,
    annote = {http://www.apmath.spbu.ru/ru/staff/pronina/publications.html},
    author = {Ю. Г. Пронина},
    date-added = {2021-10-15 22:35:00 +0200},
    date-modified = {2021-10-15 22:35:00 +0200},
    publisher = {СПбГУ},
    title ={Сборник задач по основам теории упругости: учебное пособие},
    year = {2003},
    langid = {russian}}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{texgyreadventor}
\setmathfont{xitsmath}
\usepackage[german,russian,main=english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=fonts ids]{russian}
\babelfont[russian]{rm}[Color=blue]{LiberationSans}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\setlength{\textheight}{3in}%for screen image
\begin{document}
\[ a^2+b^2=c^2 \]
Ggeabt Клэ \footcite{book1}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but 2 objections:
- It works only with lualatex. I would like to stick to pdflatex for compatability reasons.
- I think (I'm not sure) that system fonts are used here, which again destroys compatability. I would feel on the safe side, if everything is contained in packages, which Latex can download alone without having to rely on system fonts.

Comment: Check the truetype/opentype fonts that come with TeX itself (in the texmf tree), and select from those. pdflatex can only handle 8-bit fonts (128 or 256 glyphs only), so you might be lucky and someone has typed up the relevant files (probably last century) or you can do that yourself if required. Some package writers put code to detect xelatex/lualatex and switch automatically to `fontspec` and ttf/otf, and if pdflatex, switch to the 8-bit fonts (if the files are there and are not broken). With `fontspec`, you can use any ttf/otf file with `Path=` option, not just system or TeX fonts.